# Autoreload file system changes in phpstorm/webstorm/intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

Ahoi

I have an project with grunt, and whenever I save a file it runs the csscomb script in the grunt:watch task. My old "IDE" Sublime reloaded the changes automatically, phpStorm doesn't do that. I always have to manually synch the file.
The whole problem is that I write code, save in between and continue programming, and then the popup about the file system changes appears.

LG

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old stuff, but I had the same problem with WebStorm - i.e grunt running externally on a network server.

I just unchecked "use safe-write ..." in Settings > Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings and now my WS writes saves directly to the file triggering watch grunt tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you run grunt:watch outside of webStorm, or using Grunt console? In the latter case, the file system should be synchronized when task is completed. But if the task is run externally, outside of webstorm, you have to synchronize files manually

Comment: It's run outside of webStorm.

Answer (score 0):

Try Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Synchronize files on frame activation. PHPStorm will automatically reload file system changes once you switch to its window.